# Python , check if a list follows a distribution

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to find a short way to check if list elements follow a general distribution like :

```
list = [1,3,5,7,9,11]
```

the difference between list[i] and list[i+1] is clearly 2 , but the function i want needs to take in consideration also list[i+1] - list[i] >= 2 .

One liners or lambdas are welcome !

Comment: The difference between `list[i]` and `list[i+1]` is not always 2; it's `[2, 2, 1, 2, 2]`.

Comment: What's up with `5,6`? That's not a difference of 2.

Comment: Could you give a precise description of what you want your function to do? "follow a general distribution like [thing]" has too many possible interpretations.

Comment: Even after your update, what does "take into consideration also list[i+1] - list[i] >= 2" _mean_? What is the rule you want the function to apply? If you don't know a short way to write it, but do know a clunky and verbose way, then show us that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> l = [1,3,5,6,8,10]
>>> all(y - x >= 2 for x, y in zip(l, l[1:]))
False

>>> l = [1,3,5,7,9,11]
>>> all(y - x >= 2 for x, y in zip(l, l[1:]))
True
```

As usual consider [`izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) instead of `zip` if memory is a concern.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious way to compare `list[i]` and `list[i+1]` is to [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the list with its `1:` slice, then loop over the pairs:

```
for i, i1 in zip(lst, lst[1:]):
    # stuff
```

For example, to find the maximum difference:

```
maxdiff = max(i1-i for i, i1 in zip(lst, lst[1:]))
```

This has a few disadvantages if the list is gigantic, or if you want your code to work with any iterable rather than just sequences. In that case, you can easily write a function that yields adjacent pairs:

```
def pairs(i):
    i = iter(i)
    prev = next(i)
    for x in i:
        yield prev, x
        prev = x
```

Or:

```
def pairs(i):
    i1, i2 = tee(iter(i))
    next(i2)
    yield from zip(i1, i2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can i try this way:

```
>>> lis = [1,3,5,6,8,10]

>>> all(map(lambda x: x[0+1] - x[0] >= 2, enumerate(lis)))
False
>>> all(map(lambda x: x[0+1] - x[0] >= 1, enumerate(lis)))
True
>>>
```

Comment: This is needlessly obfuscated, which makes it hard to realize that it's wrong. At each point, you're subtracting `lis[i] - i`, so you get `1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5`, which only happens to have the right result for the two examples by accident.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are looking for but if your goal is just a one liner to iterate over the list and check a condition list comprehensions are a good option.

```
[list[i+1] - list[i] >= 2 for i in range(len(list)-1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
def pairwise(l):
    a,b = itertools.tee(l)
    next(b,None)
    return itertools.izip(a,b)

l = [1,3,5,6,8,10]
pairs = pairwise(iter(l))  
print(list(itertools.ifilter(lambda i: i[1] - i[0] == 2,pairs)))
```

This is using itertools.